# How to access the local project file using java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, path, nio

I am new to java.nio world.

I have a log file app.log inside my Java module. (I am using Intellij 11).

In a module, i have test folder, i have a local file app.jar.

I want to read this file into InputStream using Files.newInputStream(path) method.

The problem is that in windows, i have to give complete value for input path as,

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Perforce\\depot\\Project\\module\\src\\test\\a\\b\\c\\app.jar");
```

I am not sure if somebody gets this code and has similar folder structure on their machine to access app.jar

I have kept the file app.jar in local folder where my test is written. Is there a way through which i can generalize this Path? if my Test class is under the same folder where app.jar is residing, is there any mechanism to avoid mentioning the complete local path?

Thanks,
Vijay Bhore

Comment: My TestClass path is: "C:\\Perforce\\depot\\Project\\module\\src\\test\\a\\b\\c\\TestClass.java"

Comment: Give `Paths.get` a relative path.

Comment: do you mean Paths.get("app.jar") in my TestClass.java?

Comment: @VijarBhore It's going to depend on your file structure. I don't know how IntelliJ manages its file structure, but if that file structure was for an Eclipse project, it would be `Paths.get("src/test/a/b/c/app.jar")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path. Paths.get() will resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

That is, if app.jar is directly under you app_home folder, and app_home is where you run java.exe, then Paths.get("app.jar") should work.

Comment: Normally you define perforce repo in any folder e.g. C:/perforce in my case. Somebody might do it in C:/views. I don't want to check in TestClass.java file with my local location for app.jar file. It might be failure for other developer to check the app.jar file in C:/views if my file is in C:/perforce. Like we use local resources in web app or in normal app using relative path, can we do it for app.jar file too?

Answer (score 0):

@Jeffrey

Yeah, it had to with how intellij file system.

Normally the project root is the location where the file is searched. 
If my project root is **C:\perforce\depot\TestProject\Main** then **Paths.get("app.jar")** tries to look the file in **C:\perforce\depot\TestProject\Main\app.jar**

Actually i had a module **com.x.y.z** In this module i have src folder under which i have test root folder under which i have app.jar file.

Hence, i have to actually invoke

```
Paths.get("com.x.y.z/src/test/app.jar").
```

This solved my problem.

Thanks,

Vijay Bhore

Comment: I would suggest picking it up from your bin or class folder rather than src

Comment: As this module is a test module, i thought, the test resources can be kept directly under src/test folder. But yeah, i got your point that jar or any archive should be kept under bin or class folder.